# Add decorator to component decorator in KFP v2 in Vertex AI

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

Usually, KFP v2 supports adding a component decorator like this:

```
@component
def test():
  print("hello world")
```

I would like to add an additional decorator to add new functionality like this:

```
@component
@added_functionality
def test():
  print("hello world")
```

Where `added_functionality` is imported and looks like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def added_functionality(func):
  print("starting added functionality")

  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print("starting wrapper")
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  return wrapper
```

The issue is that when I compile the pipeline, I see 'starting added functionality' printed to the console, but "starting wrapper" doesn't show up in the log in Vertex AI. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't. This is a disappointing limitation of Kubeflow currently.